# Storing the first char of an user's input

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){  //main loop
  int rate, hours, xhours, tax, uwc, deduct, GP, NP; //rate=pay per hour, hours=hours worked, xhours=overtime
  char F_N, G_N; //Store Family name and given name

  printf("Input family name :"); //Ask Family name
  scanf("%1c", &F_N);//Store only initial of family name
  printf("\nInput given name:"); //Ask given name
  scanf(" %1c", &G_N);//Store only initial of given name
  printf("\nInput hourly rate of pay:"); //Ask for rate of pay
  scanf("%d", &rate); //Store rate of pay 

  return 0; //end the code
}
```

When I ask the user for their full name, i want to store only the first letter of their name. How do you do that?

Comment: Because `scanf()` is consuming the carriage return as input.

Comment: I think this is the most commonly posted question in this section

Comment: thanks xing that helped alot

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What similarities does the proposed duplicate have with the *actual question*? (i.e. "When I ask the user for their full name, i want to store only the first letter of their name. How do you do that?")

Comment: @Seb You're right, that is another question altogether.  But the first part is a duplicate, namely not understanding how `scanf()` works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In that case, aren't *all* `scanf`-related questions duplicates, as they're *all* based on `scanf`-related misunderstandings? Which fundamental errors are common between these two questions? Aside from discarding the return values (a common error which shouldn't bind two virtually unrelated questions together), I see none... and the proposed redirect doesn't even address that problem! This question uses the `c` and `d` format delegates; that question uses `s`...

Comment: @Seb I don't have a gold medal, and hence I don't have the authority to close a C/C++ question.  You should be directing your concerns to a moderator, who actually nailed the question close, I merely suggested it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand that. Please, just be a little more careful choosing your duplicates in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you to use `getchar` to retrieve and store the first character, it'd then make sense to use `getchar` to retrieve and discard the remainder of a line. For example:

```
int c = getchar(), F_N = c;
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    c = getchar();
```

This can mostly be done with a single `scanf` and the `*` assignment-suppression character, but `scanf` won't handle the trailing newline correctly so you need an extra `getchar()`:

```
char F_N;
if (scanf("%c%*[^\n]", &F_N) != 1) {
    /* XXX: handle scanf error */
}
getchar();
```